# How to change the default branch in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, branch

When I create a new Freestyle project in Jenkins, the default branch is "master".
Can Jenkins be configured so that the default branch is "main"[jenkins default branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FtuY.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a freestyle project, you also need to configure the section Source Code Management. In there you choose Git, and amongst other settings you enter the branch specifier. Per default it points to `*/master`.

From the online help within Jenkins:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a
> repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes
> and built.
>
> The safest way is to use the refs/heads/ syntax. This way
> the expected branch is unambiguous.
>
> If your branch name has a / in it make sure to use the full reference
> above. When not presented with a full path the plugin will only use
> the part of the string right of the last slash. Meaning foo/bar will
> actually match bar.
>
> If you use a wildcard branch specifier, with a slash (e.g. release/),
> you'll need to specify the origin repository in the branch names to
> make sure changes are picked up. So e.g. origin/release/